# Django CreateView form not getting inserted

Tags: django, forms, django-class-based-views

I'm fairly new to this, but what I'm trying to do is get my form to display  (injected as part of a template) in another view.  In developer tools I see the HTML for my included page (polls/_poll_form.html), but not the form.  I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    poll_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(
        Topic,
        related_name = 'polls',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'polls:single',
            kwargs={'pk':self.pk}
        )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'polls'
        ordering = ['last_updated_at']
```

views.py

```
  class CreatePoll(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
        template_name = 'polls/_poll_form.html'
        model = Poll
```

_poll_form.html (injected template)

```
<div class="container poll-form-header">
    <p class="text-center">Get Started</p>
</div>
<form class="create-poll-form" action="{% url 'topics:single' pk=topic.topic_id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-dark float-right">
</form>
```

topic_detail.html

```
{% extends "topics/topic_base.html" %}

{%block topics_content %}
  <div class="col-md-12 list-group polls-list">
      <div class="container new-poll-button">
        <a class = "btn btn-dark float-right mt-2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#poll-form" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Create Poll</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse mt-2 new-poll-form" id="poll-form">
        <div class="card card-body">
          {% include "polls/_poll_form.html" %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% if topic.polls.count == 0 %}
      <br>
      <div class="container no-polls-message">
        <p>There are no polls for this topic.  Create the first!</p>
      </div>
    {% else %}
      {% for poll in topic.polls.all %}
        {% include "polls/_poll.html" %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You are not passing your 'form' via views.py to your template. Can you also show us your forms.py? Maybe you forgot to make the form?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a fairly common confusion, but I don't really understand how it arises.

Just including a template in another one doesn't mean that a view which mentions that template is executed. Views render templates, templates don't call views. Views are only called by the user requesting a URL which is handled by that view. In your case, the URL is pointing to a completely different URL, and the one that creates the form is never called.

You need to include the form in the context of the view that your URL is actually calling. Either do this explicitly in the `get_context_data` method, or - if the form needs to appear on multiple pages - create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) that inserts a rendered template, including the form.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.  I was able to get the form to display.

Answer (score -1):

Make a forms.py in your app.

Write something like this:

```
from .models import Poll

class PollForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = ('name', 'topic',)
```

And then import PollForm in views.py and pass it to template

```
from polls.forms import PollForm

 class CreatePoll(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
        template_name = 'polls/_poll_form.html'
        model = Poll
        form_class = PollForm
```

Comment: There's no need for this, CreateView will automatically define a form if one is not supplied.